# Separate column on the last digit

Tags: r, regex

Say I have a df such as this:

```
x <- data.frame("SN" = 1:3, "Age" = c(21,15,2), "Name" = c("Q62yes","Q44_1_1Maybe", "Q2Some times"))
```

I would like separate out the Name column such that:

```
x_out <- data.frame("SN" = 1:3, "Age" = c(21,15,2), "Name" = c("Q62","Q44_1_1","Q2"), "New" = c("yes", 'Maybe', 'some times'))
```

I tried this, but I don't think my regex is not separating it into two groups as expected. Any suggestions?

```
x %>% 
  tidyr::separate(Name,c("name",'new'), sep = "(Q[[:digit:]]*_[[:digit:]])*([[:alpha:]]*\\s*)")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use a regex lookaround to split between a digit (`\\d`) and non-digit (`[A-Za-z]`) in `separate`

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
x %>% 
    separate(Name, into = c("Name", "New"), sep="(?<=\\d)(?=[A-Za-z])")
```

-output

```
SN Age    Name        New
1  1  21     Q62        yes
2  2  15 Q44_1_1      Maybe
3  3   2      Q2 Some times
```

---

Note that this will also work when we have no digits as well compared to `extract`

```
x$Name[3] <- "hello"
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```r
x %>% 
   tidyr::extract(Name,c("name",'new'), "(.*?\\d)([[:alpha:]].*)")
```

The regex means:

- `(.*?\d)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars as few as possible till the digit that is followed with the subsequent subpatterns
- `([[:alpha:]].*)` - Group 2: a letter and then the rest of the string.

See the [**regex demo**](https://regex101.com/r/zn6TLe/1).

R test with output:

```r
> x %>% 
+   tidyr::extract(Name,c("name",'new'), "(.*?\\d)([[:alpha:]].*)")
  SN Age    name        new
1  1  21     Q62        yes
2  2  15 Q44_1_1      Maybe
3  3   2      Q2 Some times
```

Comment: THanks, I did not know you could do with extract!

Comment: @NewBee It is safer with `extract`. Imagine you have `Q62iphone11new`, it will get split several times and the number of columns will no longer match.